# Hittint Print button in print dialogue box programatically

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I am trying to print local SSRS report through Winforms using following code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.tblGoodsInTableAdapter.Fill(Me.dbPOsDataSet.tblGoodsIn)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
Private Sub ThreadTask()
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    Thread.Sleep(10)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
End Sub

Private Sub ReportViewer1_RenderingComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.RenderingCompleteEventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.RenderingComplete
    ReportViewer1.PrintDialog()
    Dim thrd As Thread
    thrd = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
    thrd.IsBackground = True
    thrd.Start()
End Sub
```

It works fine till viewing the print Dialogue box.
I need to hit the Print button of Print dialogue box programatically, so printing is done without user intervention.
Please advise how to achieve this objective.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you also don't want to show report preview this is an interesting walkthrough by Microsoft: [Printing a Local Report without Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx).

It shows how to programmatically print a report without viewing it, using the `LocalReport` object. It's a completely different approach than your but I think this is the correct way to do it.